# Typescript equivalent to C#'s default<T>?

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, is there an equivalent to [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/generics/default-keyword-in-generic-code)?

If not, can its behaviour be implemented somehow?

example:

```
 let myNumber = default<Number>(); // 0
 let myInstance = default<MyClass>(); // null
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such thing in TypeScript:

- If the `strictNullChecks` flag is set, each type (including user-defined) would need its own `default` instance, which is not practical
- If it is unset, the default value for everything is `undefined` so there would be no point having a special `default` operator

If you need this behaviour you will have to define default functions yourself for each type that you need - and even then, you will not be able to use them generically because generic type information is not preserved at runtime

Answer (score -1):

Does this work?:

```
function def(t: any): any {
    switch (t) {
        case String: return "";
        case Number: return 0;
        case Foo: return new Foo();
        default: return null;
    }
}

let str = def(String); // = ""
let myClass = def(MyClass); // = null
```

Comment: The point of `default<T>()` is that it does not require an argument (only type).